# Complex numbered function differentiation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us think formally of $z$ and $z^*$ as independent variables for the plane, like $x$ and $y$. Then we have that 
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z*}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial(x-iy)}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}. $$

Can you explain how to derive the above equation for complex numbered functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(note: the formula in the OP is *wrong*)

Differentials tend to be better behaved, especially when multiple related variables are involved. The crucial equations are

$$ z = x + \mathbf{i} y\qquad \qquad  z^* = x - \mathbf{i} y$$

which differentiates to

$$ \mathrm{d}z = \mathrm{d} x + \mathbf{i} \mathrm{d} y 
\qquad \qquad
\mathrm{d}z^* = \mathrm{d} x - \mathbf{i} \mathrm{d} y $$

which we can solve to get

$$ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d}z + \mathrm{d}z^*}{2}
\qquad \qquad 
\mathrm{d}y = \frac{\mathrm{d}z - \mathrm{d}z^*}{2 \mathbf{i}}
$$

which we can apply if we need to switch from the $\mathrm{d}x, \mathrm{d}y$ basis to the $\mathrm{d} z, \mathrm{d} z^*$ basis.

---

For partial derivatives, $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial z^*}$ is meant to be the dual basis to $\mathrm{d}z$ and $\mathrm{d}z^*$. That is, we specifically want to have

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial z} = 1
\qquad \qquad
\frac{\partial z}{\partial z^*} = 0
\\
\frac{\partial z^*}{\partial z} = 0
\qquad \qquad
\frac{\partial z^*}{\partial z^*} = 1
$$

Similarly, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ are the dual basis to $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$, so that we have
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = 1
\qquad \qquad
\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = 0
\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0
\qquad \qquad
\frac{\partial y}{\partial y} = 1
$$

By whatever method you like, we arrive at the equations
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}
\qquad  \frac{\partial x}{\partial z^*} = \frac{1}{2}
\\
 \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2\mathbf{i}}
\qquad  \frac{\partial y}{\partial z^*} = -\frac{1}{2\mathbf{i}}
$$
or alternatively,
$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 1
\qquad  \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = \mathbf{i}
\\
 \frac{\partial z^*}{\partial x} = 1
\qquad  \frac{\partial z^*}{\partial y} = -\mathbf{i}
$$

And we can do linear algebra to express $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial z^*}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and vice versa. The end result will be

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2 \mathbf{i}} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} 
\qquad \qquad \frac{\partial}{\partial z^*} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - \frac{1}{2 \mathbf{i}} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} 
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} +  \frac{\partial}{\partial z^*}
\qquad \qquad
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \mathbf{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} - \mathbf{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial z^*}
$$

we can verify, for example, the formula for $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ by applying both sides to, for example, both $z$ and to $z^*$:

$$  \frac{\partial z}{\partial z} = 1
\qquad \qquad \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2 \mathbf{i}} \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} 
= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1$$
$$ \frac{\partial z^*}{\partial z} =0
\qquad \qquad \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial z^*}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2 \mathbf{i}} \frac{\partial z^*}{\partial y} 
= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$ x = \frac{1}{2}(z+z^*), \quad y = \frac{1}{2i}(z-z^*), $$
so
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z^*} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial z^*} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial z^*} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{1}{2i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) $$
(and in particular, the formula in the question is missing a factor of $1/2$).